# Filling QSharedPointer<T> collection in C++/Qt

Tags: c++, qt, templates, c++17, function-templates

I use C++17, GCC 7.4.0, Qt 5.12.x.

I'd like to fill `QSharedPointer<T>` collection from `QJsonArray` (serialized `Q_GADGETS`) instance using universal function (template). So, at least, QList and QVector can be filled with it (I am not trying to find high-speed approach). Assume that we have `T convert_func(const QJsonValue& value)`, which converts `QJsonValue` to `T` instance.

```
for (const auto& json_value: qAsConst(json_array)){
auto ptr = QSharedPointer<T>::create(convert_func(json_value));
collection << ptr;
}
```

So, function template must accept typical Qt containers which contains QSharedPointer (smart pointers to Q_GADGETS). How can this be achieved?

Pseudocode:

```
QJsonArray json_array;
//...
//json_array has been filled
QVector<QSharedPointer<My_gadget>> gadget_vector = fill_gadgets<QVector<QSharedPointer<My_gadget>>>(json_array);
QList<QSharedPointer<My_gadget>> gadget_list = fill_gadgets<QList<QSharedPointer<My_gadget>>>(json_array);

//or like that (QSharedPointer is mandatory, that's why is implicit):
QVector<QSharedPointer<My_gadget>> gadget_vector = fill_gadgets<QVector,My_gadget>(json_array);
QList<QSharedPointer<My_gadget>> gadget_list = fill_gadgets<QList, My_gadget>(json_array);
```

You can pretend that we have `std::array` (or other collection) instead of `QJsonArray` as an input. The problem is in description of output collection using template.

Comment: QSharedPointer<T> is not a container/collection class, so it's unclear what you want to achieve. Could you please clarify? And maybe add the declaration of your  `collection` variable as well.

Comment: zgyarmati, I've added some details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to convert from any source container (ContSource) to other container destination with some Smart Pointer in the middle , the following code snippet should make the job.

It uses template template parameter for both ContDest and ContSource. The variadic template argument for both of them are not needed if you only use Qt container as they are only templated by one argument, but if you use std containers, there are templated by the type and the Allocator.  So the code with variadic template argument works fine with both as the example show.

```
template < template <typename... Args> class ContDest,
template <typename... Args> class ContSource,
template<typename... Args> class SmartPointer,
typename E>
ContDest<SmartPointer<E>> fillGadget(const ContSource<E>& values)
{
    ContDest<SmartPointer<E>> res;
    for (const auto & val : values)
        res.push_back(SmartPointer<E>(new E(val)));

    return res;

}

const QList<int> vals = { 1,2,3 };
auto gadget_stdvector = fillGadget< std::vector, QList, std::shared_ptr, int >(vals);

std::deque<int> val2 = { 1 ,2, 3 };
auto gadget_qvector = fillGadget< QVector, std::deque, QSharedPointer, int >(val2);
```

Note that it' s sub-optimal for all the cases where Source Container and Destination Container values are stored contiguously.